# Форма обратной связи

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки и любители. Есть форма обратной связи состоящая из:

- "Имя:"
- "Адрес:"
- "Проблема:"
- Две кнопки "вызвать мастера" и "вызвать оценщика"

Вообщем суть в том, что админу при нажатии по кнопку, например, "вызвать мастера" должно в теме (или в самом письме) приходить уведомление о том, что вызвали мастера. Реально ли вообще такое сделать?!

```
<form  action="send.php" method="post" >
<p><input type="text" name="name" size="35" id="name" value="имя" onfocus="if (this.value=='имя') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='имя';"/></p>
<p><input type="text" name="adres" size="35" id="adres" value="адрес" onfocus="if (this.value=='адрес') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='адрес';"/></p>
<p><input type="text" name="problema" size="35" id="problema" value="проблема" onfocus="if (this.value=='проблема') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='проблема';"/></p>
<input type="submit" value="Вызвать мастера"><input type="submit" value="Вызвать оценщика">
</form>
```

И собственно сам обработчик:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
if (isset($_POST['adres'])) {$adres = $_POST['adres'];}
if (isset($_POST['problema'])) {$problema = $_POST['problema'];}
$address = "john198911@mail.ru";
$sub = "Онлайн-заявка";
$mes = "Имя: $name \nАдрес: $adres \nПроблема: \n$problema";
$send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email");
if ($send == 'true')
{
echo "Сообщение отправлено!";
}
else 
{
echo "Сообщение не отправлено!";
}
?>
```

Не судите строго )

Answer (score 1):

Если не вдаваясь в подробности, то в форме меняем на:

```
<input type="submit" name="master" value="Вызвать мастера"><input name="rater" type="submit" value="Вызвать оценщика">
```

А в РНРку добавляем что-то вида:

```
if (isset($_POST['master']))
    @mail ("admin@site",$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8rnFrom:$email");
```

Comment: спасибо....сейчас попытаюсь изменить

Comment: Да и ещё ж обратите внимание, что в "charset = utf-8rnFrom:" должны стоять бэкслеши "charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:"

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю сделать это через конструкцию switch case, т.е. если нажали вызов мастера, то передается в переменной $type значение 1; если нажали вызов оценщика, то передается в переменной $type значение 2.

```
switch($type) { 
    case 1:
       тут данные для отправки, если мастер
    break;
    case 2:
       тут данные для отправки, если оценщик
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

я вот так сделал

```
<?
$admin_email="vipero@hosting.polygon-delta.com";
    $name = $_GET["name"];
    $email = $_GET["email"];   
    $comment = $_GET["comment"];

echo "<form method=get action=".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']." ><table>\n";
echo "<tr><td class=\"bottom\">Name:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"$name\" /></td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><td class=\"bottom\">E-mail:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" value=\"$email\" /></td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><td valign=\"top\" class=\"bottom\">Comment:</td><td><textarea name=\"comment\" value=\"$comment\" rows=\"8\" cols=\"40\" /></textarea></td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><input type=\"submit\" /></td></tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
echo "</form>\n";

    $title = "e-mail from user";
    $comment = str_replace("&quot;","\"",$comment);   
    $comment = stripslashes($comment);
    $comment = str_replace("<br>","\n",$comment);
    $content = "The addition from $name :\n".
                "IP : ".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."\n".
                "Date & time : ".$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n".
               "----------------------------\n\n".
               $comment.
               "\n\n-----End Message-----";
    @mail($admin_email,$title,$content,"From: $email\n");
?>
```